# how to launch headless chrome with "do not track" setting with puppeteer?

Tags: headless-browser, puppeteer

How can I set "do not track" when lunching chromium in puppeteer? 
Is it possible?

Is there any option in args to set as follows.

```
 puppeteer.launch({ args=['DO_NOT_TRACK']})
```

Tried many options listed in [chromium switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but could not find the one I need. 
By setting such option, I want to avoid google analytics track.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to do it is as follows.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ DNT: "1" });
```

Comment: The header is set to "dnt". Note the lower case. Will this still evoke a DNT response?